# Why does Rspec of RubyMonk says it true where the outcome is false?

Tags: ruby

I have this:

```
 def kaprekar?(k)
   string_k = (k * k).to_s
   length_k = k.to_s.length.to_i
   length_k2 = string_k.to_s.length.to_i
   number1 = string_k[0...length_k].to_i
   number2 = string_k[length_k..length_k2].to_i 
   number1 + number2 == k 
 end
```

and according to this error message  for 297 it output is true.

> `returns true for 297`
>
> `RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError`
>
> `expected false to be true`

But when I do the same on repl.it I see this output:

```
 kaprekar?(297) 


string_k : 88209 
length_k : 3 
length2 : 5 
number1 : 882 
number2: 9 
=> false
```

which is the right answer.

Can anyone explain why Rubymonk say the outcome is true?

---

### Edit 1:

The task is:

> #### Problem Statement
>
> 9 is a Kaprekar number since
> 9 ^ 2 = 81 and 8 + 1 = 9
>
> 297 is also Kaprekar number since
> 297 ^ 2 = 88209 and 88 + 209 = 297.
>
> In short, for a Kaprekar number k with n-digits, if you square it and add the right n digits >to the left n or n-1 digits, the resultant sum is k.
>
> Find if a given number is a Kaprekar number.

---

Comment: Give us the Rspec code also.. otherwise how can we validate ?

Comment: I would do that as soon as I know how I can see the rspec file. On the site Ruby Monk you never see the actual Rspec file only the outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why Rubymonk say the outcome is true?

RubyMonk is *actually* saying that the *expected* outcome is `true`, whereas your implementation yields `false`. Your edit even states that 297 *is* a Kaprekar number. Hopefully my answer will clarify this.

Quoth [Kaprekar's Number](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/150-kaprekar-s-number) from [RubyMonk](https://rubymonk.com/) (emphasis mine):

> for a Kaprekar number *k* with *n*-digits, if you square it and add **the right *n* digits** to the left *n* or *n*-1 digits, the resultant sum is *k*.

Given *k* = 297

⇒ *n* = 3

⇒ *k*<sup>2</sup> = 88,209

⇒ Right *n* digits = 209

⇒ Left *n-1* digits = 88

⇒ 209 + 88 = 297

⇒ Right *n* digits + Left *n-1* digits = *k*

∴ `kaprekar?(297)` should return `true`.

Your solution adds **the left *n* digits** (882), to the right *n*-1 (09), which is why you get `false` (882 + 09 ≠ 297).

A [sample solution](http://repl.it/UY5/3), using [array slicing with negative indices](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-slice), may look like:

```
def kaprekar?(k)
  n = k.to_s.size
  square = (k * k).to_s
  right = square[-n..-1].to_i
  left = square[0...-n].to_i
  right + left == k
end
```